# SQL calculation with previous row + current row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, calculation

I want to make a calculation based on the excel file. I succeed to obtain 2 of the first records with LAG (as you can check on the 2nd screenshot). Im out of ideas how to proceed from now and need help. I just need the Calculation column take its previous data. I want to automatically calculate it over all the dates. I also tried to make a LAG for the calculation but manually and the result was +1 row more data instead of NULL. This is a headache.

`LAG(Data ingested, 1) OVER ( ORDER BY DATE ASC ) AS LAG`

[image: calculation]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want cumulative sums:

```
select t.*,
       (sum(reconciliation + aves - microa) over (order by date) -
        first_value(aves - microa) over (order by date)
       ) as calculation
from CalcTable t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=86cb97c6f16dd30c3d3c2294eadaccea) is a SQL Fiddle.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you just need to define a group:

```
select t.*,
       (sum(reconciliation + aves - microa) over (partition by grp order by date) -
        first_value(aves - microa) over (partition by grp order by date)
       ) as calculation
from (select t.*,
             count(nullif(reconciliation, 0)) over (order by date) as grp
      from CalcTable t
     ) t
order by date;
```

Comment: No, the results are competely different:( I think this is different than cumulative

Comment: @bulprosbibg . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle?

Comment: Lindoff here it is https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ujUhFEGxyBFA1uvUsL3PZr/0

Comment: @bulprosbibg . . . You are ignoring the the `aves` and `microa` values in the first row.  That seems suspicious, but it is the calculation you described and I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you!! Your answer seems to work okay until the second Reconcliation appears. It doest detect it and continue to calculate the values based on the first Reconcliation. Anyway, Thank you so much Gordon!

Comment: @bulprosbibg . . . The answer is easily adjusted for that.  I do not, however, see anything in your question that suggests that the sums should restart with each reconciliation (I added the answer anyway).

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! A lot! It can be viewed from my screenshot from SSMS that I took the data from Reconcliation when it is <> than 0

Answer (score 1):

Imo this could be solved using a "gaps and islands" approach.  When Reconciliation>0 then create a gap.  `SUM(GAP) OVER` converts the gaps into island groupings.  In the outer query the 'sum_over' column (which corresponds to the 'Calculation') is a cumumlative sum partitioned by the island groupings.

```
with 
gap_cte as (
    select *, case when [Reconciliation]>0 then 1 else 0 end gap
    from CalcTable),
grp_cte as (
    select *, sum(gap) over (order by [Date]) grp
    from gap_cte)
select *, sum([Reconciliation]+
               (case when gap=1 then 0 else Aves end)-
               (case when gap=1 then 0 else Microa end)) 
               over (partition by grp order by [Date]) sum_over
from grp_cte;
```

[EDIT]
The CASE statement could be CROSS APPLY'ed instead

```
with 
grp_cte as (
    select c.*, v.gap, sum(v.gap) over (order by [Date]) grp
    from #CalcTable c
         cross apply (values (case when [Reconciliation]>0 then 1 else 0 end)) v(gap))
select *, sum([Reconciliation]+
               (case when gap=1 then 0 else Aves end)-
               (case when gap=1 then 0 else Microa end)) 
               over (partition by grp order by [Date]) sum_over
from grp_cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4af3ad7c167b00d11c1d724ca3fd54e5) is a fiddle

Comment: you solutions seems to work perfectly for my case. Thank you! I really appreciate it and also this is the first time Ive heard about "gaps and islands". Thats nice!! I will apply your code in monday and If something more appear I will let you know, but for now in db fiddle seems to be perfect!! Thank you again!